# No Mapping metadata found

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for java.lang.Object
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:140)

I am receiving this error when attempting to retrieve a document from my couchbase server. The document is a simple JSON object with a nested object inside as well as lists of JSON objects. I am able to get the document successfully when the document only contains the lists, but not when the nested object is present.

Do I have to define any nested object as a java class for couchbase and spring to cooperate, or am I missing something.

Comment: I am facing the exact same error. Did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36867857/3430316