# MappingException for Map type of data

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

While saving Map type data in couchBase I am getting an exception

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type java.lang.Object!

I've taken a map in DataModel

```
@Data
public class test { 
  private Map<String,Object> testMap;
 }
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002986/no-mapping-metadata-found-for-java-lang-object-couchbase/36867857) and override couchBase configuration to do customMapping in case of Object Type like

```
protected <R> R read(final TypeInformation<R> type, final CouchbaseDocument source,
        final Object parent) {
      if (Object.class == typeMapper.readType(source, type).getType()) {
        return (R) source.export();
      } else {
        return super.read(type, source, parent);
      }
    }
```

It worked for the request like

```
{  
   "dummyMap":{  
      "key1":"val1",
      "key2":"val2"
   }
}
```

But failed for

```
{  
   "dummyMap":{  
      "key1":"val1",
      "key2":"val2",
      "objects":[  
         {  
            "key1":"val1",
            "key2":"val2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

with exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Basic type must not be null!

I guess it is because of the array. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

I am using spring-data-couchbase version 2.0.4.RELEASE.

Comment: That's because of the array. Face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

hi please use below code, its because type is null and couchbase mapping convertor cant read document
its must be work.

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <R> R read(final TypeInformation<R> type, final CouchbaseDocument source, final Object parent) {
        if (type == null)
            return (R) source.export();
        if (Object.class == typeMapper.readType(source, type).getType()) {
            return (R) source.export();
        } else {
            return super.read(type, source, parent);
        }
    }
```