# Spring Boot retrieve data from Couchbase for HashMap type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I need to store dynamic data on Couchbase and I am using Spring Boot. When I send a request with dynamic data, it is stored on Couchbase successfully. But when I try to retrieve data with `repo.findAll(pageable)`, I am getting an error.

My entity class

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Field
    private String name;

    @Field
    private HashMap dynamicData;
}
```

When I send a request with this body, it is stored on Couchbase successfully.

```
{

    "name":"mike",  
    "dynamicData":{
        "school":"test school",
        "lessons":[
            {
                "name":"data structure",
                "type":"ce"
            },{
                "name":"computer vision",
                "type":"ce"
            }]
    }

}
```

But when i try to get all data from Couchbase with `repo.findAll(pageable)`, I am getting this error as HTTP response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-30T19:23:36.310+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Basic type must not be null!",
    "path": "/api/v1/students"
}
```

When I don't use `HashMap` type field, everything works great.
How can I store dynamic data with `HashMap` type on CouchDB and retrieve data from Couchbase?

error:

```
2019-07-01 00:46:30.885 ERROR 16928 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target type must not be null!] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target type must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readCollection(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:695) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readMap(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:333) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:210) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:809) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.access$400(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:873) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.getValueInternal(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:279) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:246) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:240) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:355) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:240) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:214) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:172) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.mapToEntity(CouchbaseTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.findByN1QL(CouchbaseTemplate.java:460) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeCollection(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:157) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeDependingOnType(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:132) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.execute(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:107) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.ViewPostProcessor$ViewInterceptor.invoke(ViewPostProcessor.java:87) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.1.9.RELEASE.jar:3.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.customGetAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ertgamgam.sampleapi.controllers.StudentController.findAll(StudentController.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Please enable the debug level logging for spring-data-couchbase and print what N1QL query is been fired: 
"Executing N1QL query: "?

Comment: That's becasue of the array as the value, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705146/mappingexception-for-map-type-of-data